# Is there any way to split string into array by spaces in another string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two input strings. In the first one - words with spaces. In the second - the word with same count of symbols without spaces. The task is to split the second string into array by spaces in the first one.

I tried to make it with cycles but there is problem of index out of range and i can't find another solution.

```
a = str(input())
b = str(input())
b_word = str()
b_array = list()

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != " ":
        b_word += b[i]
    else:
        b_array += b_word
        b_word = str()
print(b_array)
```

Input:

```
>>head eat
>>aaabbbb
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    b_word += b[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Expected output:

```
>> ["aaab", "bbb"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the error message - "IndexError: string index out of range". Did you investigate what this error means? If you research error messages to find out what is responsible for causing them, it will help you debug errors independently. `IndexError` means that your index `i` is invalid for what you're trying to do (in this case it's bigger than the amount of elements in `b`). Have a look at your code and inputs and try to figure out how that could have occurred.

Comment: John, thank you for an answer! i understand thiis message, i just put my incorrect code

Comment: what shoud be the result for this strings `s1 = 'head eat or'`
`s2 = 'aaaabbbbbcc'` ?

Comment: hi Roman! i think error, because there more symbols in the "s2"

Comment: @DronAdron, no, there have equal size in symbols (11). So, should be the result?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i mean symbols without spaces, so there should be an error. in s1 there is 9 symbols without spaces and in s2 eleven symbols , so it's not equal

Comment: @DronAdron, Ok, I've found pretty short solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = input()  # you don't need to wrap these in str() since in python3 input always returns a string
b = input()
output = list()

for i in a.split(' '):  # split input a by spaces
    output.append(b[:len(i)])  # split input b
    b = b[len(i):]  # update b

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
['aaab', 'bbb']
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a solution based on iterator and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) method:

```
import itertools

def split_by_space(s1, s2):
    chunks = s1.split()
    it = iter(s2)   # second string as iterator
    return [''.join(itertools.islice(it, len(c))) for c in chunks]


print(split_by_space('head eat or', 'aaaabbbcc'))  # ['aaaa', 'bbb', 'cc']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
a = input()
b = input()

splitted_b = []
idx = 0
for word in a.split():
    w_len = len(word)
    splitted_b.append(b[idx:idx+w_len])
    idx += w_len

print(splitted_b)
```

The idea is taking consecutive sub-strings from `b` of the length of each word on `a`.

Comment: Well, I supposed consecutive spaces as only one space...in the code I wrote `head     eat` is a valid input and it stills print `['aaab', 'bbb']`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using indices, you can iterate over each character of `a`. If the character is not a space, add the next character of `b` to your `b_word`. If it is a space, add `b_word` to the `b_array`

```
b_iter = iter(b) # Create an iterator from b so we can get the next character when needed

b_word = []
b_array = []

for char in a:
    # If char is a space, and b_word isn't empty, append it to the result
    if char == " " and b_word:
        b_array.append("".join(b_word))
        b_word = []
    else:
        b_word.append(next(b_iter)) # Append the next character from b to b_word

if b_word: # If anything left over in b_word, append it to the result
    b_array.append("".join(b_word))
```

Which gives `b_array = ['aaab', 'bbb']`

Note that I changed `b_word` to a *list* that I `.append` to every time I add a character. This prevents the entire string from being recreated every time you append a character.
Then join all the characters using `"".join(b_word)` before appending it to `b_array`.

Answer (score 0):

So to accomodate for any number of spaces in the input it gets a bit more complex as the indexes of the letters will change with each space that is added. So to gather all of the spaces in the string I created this loop which will account of the multiple spaces and alter the index with each new space in the initial word.

```
indexs = []
new = ''
for i in range(len(a)):
    if len(indexs) > 0:
        if a[i] == ' ':
            indexs.append(i-len(indexs))
    else:
        if a[i] == ' ':
            indexs.append(i)
```

Then we simple concatenate them together to create a new string that includes spaces at the predetermined indexes.

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    if i in indexs:
        print(i)
        new += " "
        new += b[i]
    else:
        new += b[i]
print(new)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe this will only work if input a only has 1 space.

Comment: I changed it to be more universal, this was a fun challenge to work on thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

---

```
sone = input()                 
stwo = 'zzzzzxxxyyyyy'
nwz = []
wrd = ''
cnt = 0
idx = 0

spc = sone.split(' ')      #split by whitespace
a = [len(i) for i in spc]  #list word lengths w/out ws

for i in stwo:
  if cnt == a[idx]:        #if current iter eq. word length w/out ws
    nwz.append(wrd)        #append the word
    wrd = ''               #clear old word
    wrd = wrd + i          #start new word
    idx = idx + 1            
    cnt = 0
    
  else:
    wrd = wrd + i          #building word
  cnt = cnt + 1
    
nwz.append(wrd)            #append remaining word
print(nwz)
```

**Result**

---

```
>'split and match'
['zzzzz', 'xxx', 'yyyyy']
```